# Is there a way to reduce a specific quintic to cubic?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quintics, sangaku

A polynomial in two variables, $t$ and $c$,
is quintic in $t$ and quartic in $c$:

\begin{align} 
16\,t^5
-8\,c (5\,c +2) t^4
+c^2 (25\,c^2+20\,c + 36) t^3&
\\
-4\,c (11\,c^3+8\,c^2+5\,c+2) t^2&
+8\,c^2 ( 3\,c^2+3\,c+2 ) t
-4\,c^3 (c+2)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
(25 t^3-44 t^2+24 t-4)\,c^4
+(20 t^3-32 t^2+24 t-8)\,c^3
-4 t (10 t^3-9 t^2+5 t-4)\,c^2
-8 t^2 (2 t^2+1)\,c
+16 t^5
\tag{2}\label{2}
. 
\end{align}

It is related to
[An ancient Japanese geometry problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234981/122782)

[image]

Given isosceles $\triangle ABC$
with legs $|AC|=|BC|=1$ and base $|AB|=c$,
find $t=|BD|$ which provides
the same radius for all three circles,
inscribed in triangles
$ADC$, $ABE$ and $BDE$.

The roots of polynomial \eqref{1} provides the answer to this question,
and for any valid value of $c\in(0,2)$
this quintic always has only three real roots.

This drawing demonstrates
that zeros of \eqref{1}
are presented by
the three distinct branches.

[image]

Only one branch (the orange one)
provides the pairs $(c,t)$
which correspond
to correct geometric construction.

There are two "nice" points on that branch:
one corresponds to the original sangaku,
$t=c=0.56$,
another one is located at the intersection
of the two branches:
$c=3-\sqrt7$, $t=0.5$.

Curiously, the valid range for $t$ is not $(0,1)$
as one might expect, so the quartic expression \eqref{2}
may be misleading. For example, solving \eqref{2}
for $t=\tfrac34=0.75$, we find
$c=\frac{4\sqrt{61}-25}{13}\approx0.48$. However, since this $c\in(0,2)$, substituting this back into \eqref{2}, one gets the *three* real branches of the quintic as $t = 0.75, \, 0.5397,  \,0.2284$ (approx) as can be seen in graph, with the correct solution being the middle one $t = 0.5397$ (approx).

So, the **question** is:
is it possible
to reduce the quintic \eqref{1} to a cubic?

Comment: What charting tool did you use to draw this nice chart? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a chance (1) has a root repeated 3 times, such that $f(x)=(x-r_1)^3(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$? if so, equating the 2nd derivative to zero and solving the cubic equation could reveal the root $r_1$.

Comment: No, you can't reduce to a cubic because the polynomial (in two indeterminates $t,c$) is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @NoChance: Thank's for asking, this is [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).
It not only helps to draw the chart, but actually finds the roots.

Comment: @g.kov, Thank you much :)

Comment: @user10354138, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @g.kov I think I see where you are getting at. Since for appropriate $c$, the quintic has three real branches, I assume you are hoping for a formula that expresses only those branches, hence a formula of degree three. In other words, a cubic. In [Blue's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236854/4781) to the link you provided, there is a cubic formula there using trigonometric functions, but it is hard to keep track of the changes in notation between your post and that post.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a cubic factor over the integers capturing all the real roots.

For the case $c=1$ the quintic equation for $t$ becomes

$16t^5-56t^4+81t^3-104t^2+64t-12=0,$

in which the roots of a proposed cubic factor over the integers would add up to $m/n$ where $m$ divides the constant term $-12$ and $n$ divides the leading coefficient $16$. But numerical calculation to three decimal places gives the real roots as $0.323,0.634,2.197$, whose sum $3.154$ is not within the roundoff error of any whole number divided by $16$. Therefore the proposed cubic factor over the integers does not exist.

Comment: You made a small typo while typing. The three real roots you gave are correct, but the coefficient of the $t^4$ term should be $-56$ per the OP's formula. Kindly make the correction.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I can't even transcribe my own writings.

Comment: No worries. Happens to all of us. :)