# Approximating function for the root of quintic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, approximation, sangaku

Related to 
[An ancient Japanese geometry problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1234981/122782)

As illustrated in
[the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263862),
one branch of the solution to the equation

\begin{align} 
16\,t^5
-8\,c (5\,c +2) t^4
+c^2 (25\,c^2+20\,c + 36) t^3&
\\
-4\,c (11\,c^3+8\,c^2+5\,c+2) t^2&
+8\,c^2 ( 3\,c^2+3\,c+2 ) t
-4\,c^3 (c+2)
=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
(which is quintic in $t$
and quartic in $c$)
corresponds to a valid partitioning 
(with the three congruent incircles)
of the isosceles triangle
with the unit legs and the base $c$.

So it would be nice 
to have the representation of this branch
in a form of some sort of 
a function $f:c\to t$
in order to be able to make a proper construction easily,
since the process of solving quintic equations 
in known to be messy.

Luckily, it is possible to find much more "exact" points on that curve:
feeding \eqref{1} with some rational value of $t$, we get
a quartic in $c$, which, surprisingly, 
mostly results in more-or-less "digestible" expressions
in terms of square roots.
For example, the exact value of $t=\tfrac35=0.6$
corresponds to 
$c=-5+\tfrac45\sqrt{85}-\tfrac15\sqrt{2075-218\sqrt{85}}\approx 0.761457$.

Unfortunately,
the bigger integers are used in the rational $t$,
the bigger numbers appear in the expression for $c$,
so at some point it becomes unpractical.

On the other hand, feeding the value of $c$ into \eqref{1}
looks to be less fruitful, it mostly results in 
an unsolvable quintic. 
Even the equilateral case, when $c=1$, results in

\begin{align}
16t^5-56t^4+81t^3-104t^2+64t-12&=0
,
\end{align} 
for which
the 
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve(16*t%5E5-56*t%5E4%2B81*t%5E3-104*t%5E2%2B64*t-12%3D0,t))
gives only numeric output with the three real roots:

[image]

In this case the correct root is $t\approx 0.6343989078979$
and the corresponding picture is

[image]

Also, an interesting case corresponds to the 
end point of the branch,
a "collapsed" triangle
with $c=2$. In this case the quintic factors out

\begin{align}
16t^5-192t^4+704t^3-1056t^2+640t-128
&=
16(t^3-8t^2+8t-2)(t-2)^2
\end{align}
and we have a closed-form expression

\begin{align}
t&=\tfrac83-\tfrac23\sqrt{10}
\cos(\tfrac13\arctan(\tfrac 3{251}\sqrt{111}))
+\tfrac23\sqrt{30}\sin(\tfrac13\arctan(\tfrac3{251}\sqrt{111}))
\\
&\approx 0.71274226238
.
\end{align}

For the reference, this is the list of all "exact" pairs $(c,t)$:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
             & c & t
\\ \hline
1&0.0000000000&0.0000000000 \\
2&0.0002511171&0.0500000000 \\
3&0.0020326859&0.1000000000 \\
4&0.0085083955&0.1600000000 \\
5&0.0169302697&0.2000000000 \\
6&0.0340089030&0.2500000000 \\
7&0.0608062789&0.3000000000 \\
8&0.1006330785&0.3500000000 \\
9&0.1579689782&0.4000000000 \\
10&0.1871535034&0.4200000000 \\
11&0.2287638337&0.4444444444 \\
12&0.3033618942&0.4800000000 \\
13&0.3542486889&0.5000000000 \\
14&0.4456874846&0.5300000000 \\
15&0.5189509162&0.5500000000 \\
16&0.5600000000&0.5600000000 \\
17&0.6524875367&0.5800000000 \\
18&0.7614570341&0.6000000000 \\
19&0.8233447531&0.6100000000 \\
20&0.9271847561&0.6250000000 \\
21&1.0160639236&0.6363636364 \\
22&1.1365368495&0.6500000000 \\
23&1.2361295561&0.6600000000 \\
24&1.3086349633&0.6666666667 \\
25&1.4070647569&0.6750000000 \\
26&1.4707414304&0.6800000000 \\
27&1.5382434439&0.6850000000 \\
28&1.6099068664&0.6900000000 \\
29&1.6861084399&0.6950000000 \\
30&1.7672719250&0.7000000000 \\
31&1.8360946829&0.7040000000 \\
32&1.9148985973&0.7083333333 \\
33&2.0000000000&0.7127422624 \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$

[image]

so it was possible to find 
an approximation of the form
\begin{align} 
t\approx
f_a(c)&=a_0\,c^{a_1}-a_2\,c^{a_3}
,\\
\text{where}\quad
a_0&=0.8607785404155162
,\\
a_1&=0.3444908412558547
,\\
a_2&=0.22578038518570656
,\\
a_3&=0.7556569650006819
.
\end{align}

This approximation works surprisingly well - 
the maximal deviation of the mentioned interpolation points
is about $0.001$, which would be unnoticed 
in the illustrative drawings.

At least this approximation can be used 
to feed an initial value to 
the numerical root-finding methods
 using, for example,
[Halley’s root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Halley%27s_method)
 to get more accurate result.

**Question:** Any suggestions on the better/simpler approximating function
(not piecewise interpolation)?